# What's an effective way to reuse ArrayLists in a for loop?

Tags: java

I'm reusing the same ArrayList in a for loop, and I use

```
for loop
    results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    experts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    output = new ArrayList<String>();
....
```

to create new ones.

I guess this is wrong, because I'm allocating new memory. Is this correct ?
If yes, how can I empty them ?

**Added:** another example

I'm creating new variables each time I call this method. Is this good practice ? I mean to create new precision, relevantFound.. etc ? Or should I declare them in my class, outside the method to not allocate more and more memory ?

```
public static void computeMAP(ArrayList<Integer> results, ArrayList<Integer> experts) {

  //compute MAP
  double precision = 0;
  int relevantFound = 0;
  double sumprecision = 0;
```

thanks

Comment: What does the whole loop or code section look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ArrayList.clear()` will empty them for you; note that doing it your way is also 'okay', since Java is garbage-collected, so the old allocations will eventually get cleaned up. Still, it's better to avoid lots of new allocations (and garbage generation), so the better way would be to move those declarations outside the loop and put in calls to `clear` inside it.

For your second example, either way is fine; primitive types are typically going to get allocated only once (on the stack, when you enter the function), declaring them inside a loop doesn't increase the cost any. It's only heap allocations (i.e. calls to `new`) you need to worry about.

In response to comment:
If it doesn't make sense for those things to be instance members, then don't make them such. Also, using `new` to 'clean' them means allocating new objects every time; definitely don't do that - if your method needs a new copy of something every time it's invoked, and it isn't used anywhere except that method, then it has no business being an instance variable.
In general, worrying about such micro-optimizations at this point is counter-productive; you only think about it if you really, absolutely have to, and then *measure* whether there's a benefit before doing anything.

Comment: ok cool thanks. One more question about the second point: if I need to use other objects instead of primitives inside my method, should I declare them in my class instead of inside the method ? And can I use the new statement to clean them (in case they don't have clean methods) ?

Comment: Would making the such ArrayLists static instance variables help in re-using them?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - Variables are either instance or static, not both. And making them static would share them across different instances which will very likely lead to buggy behavior. In any case, unless you're sure (via profiling) that _allocating_ the lists is a performance bottleneck, you're likely worrying about the wrong thing. Code clarity wins over questionable 'optimization' tricks in my book.

Comment: @tzaman  I meant static member variables.  If they are shared across instances, then they wouldn't create additional objects with the 'new' statement.

Comment: Yes, but read the rest of my comment. Having static member variables just to save on allocating a few ArrayLists confuses your code and makes it more error-prone (and non-threadsafe) for very likely no actual performance gain. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet below measures the difference between allocating a new list inside the loop and calling `clear()` to reuse an existing list.

Allocating a new list is slower, as pointed out a few times above. This gives an idea of how much.

Note that the code loops 100,000 times to get those numbers. For UI code the difference may not matter. For other applications it can be a significant improvement to reuse the list.

This is the result of three runs:

```
Elapsed time - in the loop: 2198 
Elapsed time - with clear(): 1621

Elapsed time - in the loop: 2291 
Elapsed time - with clear(): 1621   

Elapsed time - in the loop: 2182 
Elapsed time - with clear(): 1605
```

Having said that, if the lists are holding hundreds or even thousands of objects, the allocation of the array itself will pale in comparison with the allocation of the objects. The performance bottleneck will be related to the objects being added to the array, not with the array.

For completeness: code was measured with Java 1.6.0_19, running on a Centrino 2 laptop with Windows. However, the main point is the difference between them, not the exact number.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)    {

      // Allocates a new list inside the loop
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
         List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
         for( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
            l1.add( "test" );
      }
      System.out.println( "Elapsed time - in the loop: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) );

      // Reuse the list
      startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
      for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
         l2.clear();
         for( int j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
            l2.add( "test" );
      }
      System.out.println( "Elapsed time - with clear(): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort of trying it out and getting numbers... which is vital whenever you optimise (other than trivial stuff like getting rid of that bubble sort). Your test is broken however. Try setting the inital arraylist size to 1000 and re-run.

Comment: Good point about the initial allocation. I lost track of that when testing the array allocation. This is what happens when the list has an initial size of 1,000 elements: Elapsed time - in the loop: 1713,  Elapsed time - with clear() 1569. That tells me most of the "clear()" time saving is actually from having an array that already has enough capacity. The focus of the optimization should be on getting that part right, not so much avoiding the allocation in the loop. There is still a difference, but not so large anymore (~10% - critical for tight loops, not so bad for most applications IMHO).

Comment: @chr  You said "objects being added to the array".  Didn't you mean ArrayList?

Comment: That would would be the strictly correct description. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

first, allocating primitive types is practically free in java, so don't worry about that.

with regard to objects, it really depends on the loop. if it's a tight loop to 100k then yes, it's a big deal to allocate 3 array list objects each time through the loop. it'd be better to allocate them outside of the loop and use List.clear().

you also have to consider where the code is running. if it's a mobile platform you will be more concerned about frequent garbage collection than you would on a server with 256GB of ram and 64 CPUs.

that all being said, no one if going to beat you up for coding for performance, whatever the platform. performance is often a trade off with code cleanliness. for example, on the android platform they recommend using the for (int i = 0 ...) syntax to loop through array lists vs. for (Object o: someList). the latter method is cleaner, but on a mobile platform the performance difference is significant. in this case i don't think clear()'ing outside of the loop makes things any harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists allocate a default memory for 5 entries. These entries are references, which need 4 bytes each (depending on architecture, maybe even 8 byte). An array list contains an int for its "real" length, which are already 24 bytes. Add the default 16 bytes, which every object (even without instance variables) has, so you at with at least 40 bytes for each ArrayList(). Depending if the store them all, or how many you have, this might be a performance loss.

Not however, that starting with Java 1.6.16, the JVM has a (default off?) feature, which "inlines" objects within a function, if no access to those objects leaves the methods context. In this case all instance variables are compiled in as being used as "local" instance variables of the calling function, so no real objects will be created.

Comment: I doubt it inlines the actual contents array of the `ArrayList`, even if it inlines the `ArrayList` itself.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: It inlines the instance variables of ArrayList, and and of those is an Object[], to which the reference is inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue to take into consideration here is how garbage collection is affected. It is clear that reusing the same ArrayList references and using ArrayList.clear() reduces instance creations.

However, garbage collection is not so simple, and apparently here we force 'old' objects to reference 'newer' objects. That means more old-to-young references (i.e. references from objects in the old generation to ones in the young generation). This kind of references result in more work during garbage collection (See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11253/) for example).

I never tried to benchmark this, and I don't know how significant this is, but I thought it could be relevant for this discussion. Maybe if the number of list items significantly outnumbers the number of lists, it is not worthwhile to use the same lists.